# Why do Exchange Display Name changes not appear in PowerShell?

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2013

I used the Exchange 2013 ECP to update all of my inactive mailboxes by adding "zzz" before their Display Name. (Only the Display Name field was affected).

In PowerShell, I want to list all mailboxes by mailbox size using the following command:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server MCC-INTMAIL | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft Displayname,Totalitemsize
```

The command works perfectly however, the updates which I made in the ECP do not appear in PowerShell. For example. I changed "Joe Blogs" to "zzz Joe Blogs" however, in PowerShell, it still appears as "Joe Blogs".

Are there any commands which will force the information to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting a day, the data automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer in the form of 'this is why that's happening' and 'here's the property to look for', try viewing all of the propertied of the object coming down the pipline to see if the edit is actually appearing in a property you're not expecting:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server MCC-INTMAIL | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | Select *
```

Also, if this is an ActiveDirectory environment, check the object in there as well to see if it has been edited on that end.

Finally, if you have multiple exchange servers, make sure they are replicating the changes between them, i.e. check the ECP on the others.